# Extracting XML elements by attribute value

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I am setting up a little movie DB website and my data is in XML format. I have two xml tags for stars, one male and one female. How can I extract the data? I have tried `$(this).find("star").text();` but that pulls both.. I tried `$(this).find("star").attr("male").text();` and that does nothing.

Here is my XML

```
<movie name = "Terminator 2 Judgment Day">
    <picture>../images/T2.jpg</picture>
    <info>
      <director>James Cameron</director>
      <star type = "male">Arnold Shwarzenegger</star>
      <star type = "female">Linda Hamilton</star>
    </info>
```

Can anyone tell me how to set this up so I can get each one, separately?
so it could be like

```
Male Lead: name
female lead: name
```

for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to filter element by attribute value like so :

```
var maleStar = $(this).find("star[type='male']").text();
var femaleStar = $(this).find("star[type='female']").text();
```

Basically, pattern for the selector is : `elementName[attributeName='attribute value']`

Comment: You, sir. Are a saint.